# Why doesn't Vue close websocket connections when i navigate to other pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a Vue app, this is my first SPA and a lot of concepts are not completely clear to me yet.

In one component i'm creating a websocket connection like that:

```
created(){
  this.connection = new WebSocket('ws://MY-URL);
  this.connection.onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log(event)
  }
}
```

This works without any problem, but suppose that i navigate to a different url in my spa, the websocket connection will not be closed, which means that even though i don't need to receive websocket messages (since i'm on a different page) i will keep receiving them, which is not really good for resource usage on the client side.

Other than that, if i navigate again to the original component where the websocket connection is started, another connection will be created, which means that i'm going to have two websocket connections sending the same messages at the same time. Why isn't the connection closed once the page is left? How can i close it, then?

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#unmounted

Comment: How did you go about confirming that the socket is still connected when you navigate elsewhere?

Comment: @Sysix is there something like that for Vue2 too?

Comment: @MattU i used Chrome network tools

Comment: Vue doesn't close your socket because it's unaware of it, it's your responsibility to do this. Check https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks , it's the first thing to learn about Vue. `destroyed` hook was there from the start because it's essential for such cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this is what i needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are using vue-router. To navigate to another route, you may use [Navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) within your component to handle your code.

For example, if your current route loads Page.vue, add the following nav-guard to it:

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    // called when the route that renders this component is about to
    // be navigated away from.
    // has access to `this` component instance.

    //this.connection is your ws
    this.connection.close()
    next()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Should this code go inside of my component?

Comment: That is correct, it will register an in-component hook into vue-router. This is similar to Vue's lifecycle hooks ( for example created () used in your code ).

Answer (score 1):

simply use this if you want to close websocket connection on component close, or changes,

```
unmounted() {
    this.connection.close();
    this. Connection = null; // to prevent memory leacking
    console.log("Closing connection to WebSocket Server")
  },
```